# Facebook graph return only the id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used Facebook SDK for get share count for posts in web site, but when I send the request the responses is only the id

```
  $link = 'url-i-want-get-share-count';
$access_token="My-Access-token";
$app_id="My-app-id";
$app_secret="My-app-secret";


$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    'default_access_token' => $access_token, // optional
]);
try {
    
    $request = $fb->get('/' . $link . '/posts?fields=og_object{engagement}');

} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($request);
```

the response is[image]

Comment: `og_object` is for Open Graph objects, which is _external_ URLs.

Comment: yes, I want get share count for external URLs (for posts in web site)

Comment: Then why are you using `/posts` in your request?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/url